# Why is the table misaligned? (The table created at the bottom of the code isn't aligned proplerly like the example at the top.)

Tags: java, math

I am working on a project and have finished the first part of the code to create a table of powers from data entered by the user. In the second part of the code, in the "method" "RemainderOperation"  I need to put in the code that will create a table with remainders that looks like this:(The numbers 6 and 3 are examples that have been put in. I have put the code up till the word "Remainders", but the table doesn;t appear correctly.)

Enter the maximum numerator: 6
Enter the maximum denominator: 3
The maximum numerator is 6 and the maximum denominator is 3.

Remainders

```
 n    n%1  n%2  n%3
 1    0    1    1
 2    0    0    2
 3    0    1    0
 4    0    0    1
 5    0    1    2
 6    0    0    0
```

---

```
 //The purpose of this program is to print a table showing the powers of a number entered by the user.
//Also to print a table showing the results of the remainder operation.

import java.util.*;
public class Tables{
  public static final Scanner KB = new Scanner(System.in);
  public static void main(String []args) {


    TableofPowers();
    RemainderOperation();

  }

    public static void TableofPowers(){
    int b, me, value;
    System.out.print("Enter the base: ");
    b = KB.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter the maximum exponent: ");
    me = KB.nextInt();
    System.out.println("The base is " + b + " and the maximum exponent is " + me);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Powers of " + b);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("x  " + b + "^x");
    value = 0;
    for(value=0; value<=me; value=value+1){
      System.out.println(value+"  " + (int)Math.pow(b,value)); 
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    }



    public static void RemainderOperation(){
    int n, d;
    System.out.print("Enter the maximum numerator: ");
    n = KB.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter the maximum denominator: ");
    d = KB.nextInt();
    System.out.println("The maximum numerator is " + n + " and the maximum denominator is " + d);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Remainders");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("\t" +"n");
    for(d=1; d <=3 ; d++){
      System.out.print("\t" + "n%" + d);
    }
    System.out.println();
    for(n = 1; n <=6; n++){
      System.out.println("\t" + n);
      System.out.println();
    for(d = 1; d <=3; d++){  
      System.out.print("\t" + n % d);
    }
    }
    }  
  }
```

Comment: My question is that out of 2 tables in my code, the second one (at the bottom) isn't aligned correctly, like the example I show at the top. It contains the correct results, but isn't appearing properly. The numbers aren't in the correct places in the rows and columns and it's mainly an issue where the numbers are in the next column over.

Comment: I've seen a *very* similar question recently, although I can't find it now. Has that one been deleted? If so, re-posting a deleted question is usually not a good idea unless you massively improve the question.

Comment: What do your printed tables actually look like. It might help if you show an image of what you are getting.

Comment: Tabs really aren't a very good way to format output since they can vary so much based upon terminal tab settings, etc. You should be using a String.format method.